# Why won't my systems of difference equations be solved?

Tags: differential-equations

I have

```
RSolve[
{k[t + 1] == 1/(1*(1 + .015)) (.2*(k[t])^(1/3)*(h[t])^(1/3) + (1 - .06)*k[t]), 
h[t + 1] == 1/(1*(1 + .015)) (.2*(k[t])^(1/3)*(h[t])^(1/3) + (1 - .06)*h[t]), 
k[1] == 12, h[1] == 16}, {k[t], h[t]}, t]
```

I know the solution is (edit: due to me missing a parenthesis the solution returns 18), but Mathematica just returns what I typed in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are expecting numeric values rather than functions of `t` then you must be looking for fixed points, i.e., the limits of the functions as `t -> Infinity`

```
Clear[h, k]

eqns = {k[t + 1] == 
     1/(1*(1 + .015)) (.2*(k[t])^(1/3)*(h[t])^(1/3) + (1 - .06)*k[t]), 
    h[t + 1] == 
     1/(1*(1 + .015)) (.2*(k[t])^(1/3)*(h[t])^(1/3) + (1 - .06)*h[t]), 
    k[1] == 12, h[1] == 16} // Rationalize // Simplify

(* {40 h[t]^(1/3) k[t]^(1/3) + 188 k[t] == 203 k[1 + t], 
 188 h[t] + 40 h[t]^(1/3) k[t]^(1/3) == 203 h[1 + t], k[1] == 12, h[1] == 16} *)
```

The fixed point equations are then

```
eqnsFP = {40*h^(1/3)*k^(1/3) + 188*k == 203*k, 
   188*h + 40*h^(1/3)*k^(1/3) == 203*h, h > 0, k > 0};

sol = Solve[eqnsFP, {h, k}][[1]]

(* {h -> 512/27, k -> 512/27} *)
```

Verifying that `sol` satisfies the fixed point equations

```
eqnsFP /. sol

(* {True, True, True, True} *)
```

The approximate numeric values are

```
sol // N

(* {h -> 18.963, k -> 18.963} *)
```

**EDIT:** Doing it iteratively with [`FixedPoint`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FixedPoint.html)

```
FixedPoint[{(40.*#[[1]]^(1/3)*#[[2]]^(1/3) + 188*#[[1]])/203,
   (40.*#[[1]]^(1/3)*#[[2]]^(1/3) + 188*#[[2]])/203} &, {16, 12}]

(* {18.963, 18.963} *)
```

**EDIT 2:** Converting the real numbers to closest rational or algebraic number

```
#[%] & /@ {Rationalize, RootApproximant}

(* {{512/27, 512/27}, {512/27, 512/27}} *)
```

Comment: Is there any way to let Mathematica iteratively come to a solution? I know that there is a closed for solution for k[t] and h[t], I just want Mathematica to numerically arrive there.

Answer (score 5):

Well, you can quickly get the numeric values by this function:

```
RecurrenceTable[{k[t + 1] == 
1/(1*(1 + .015)) (.2*(k[t])^(1/3)*(h[t])^(1/3) + (1 - .06)*k[t]), 
h[t + 1] == 
1/(1*(1 + .015)) (.2*(k[t])^(1/3)*(h[t])^(1/3) + (1 - .06)*h[t]), 
k[1] == 12, h[1] == 16}, {k[t], h[t]}, {t, 1, 530}];
```

You can change the steps to find when it turns to be couverged.

```
%[[520 ;; 530]]
```

Then the output is :

```
{{18.9629, 18.9629}, {18.9629, 18.9629}, {18.963, 18.963}, {18.963, 
18.963}, {18.963, 18.963}, {18.963, 18.963}, {18.963, 
18.963}, {18.963, 18.963}, {18.963, 18.963}, {18.963, 
18.963}, {18.963, 18.963}}
```